# JavaScript eventListener mousemove

Tags: javascript, function, callback

How does the `u` log in the value of the coordinate of the mouse?

```
div = document.querySelector('.div');

div.addEventListener('mousemove', function yo(u) {
  console.log(u);
});
```

This logs the value of x and y coordinate of the mouse.

Comment: `u` is the event object, it includes the coordinates inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to  [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp) API reference:

document.addEventListener(event, function, useCapture)

is the function prototype that takes in an event type string as the first argument a "callback" function as the second argument and a third argument true or false indicating in which phase the function should be called.

When the callback activates an event object is passed to the declared function, the type depending on the type of callback.

In the case of "mousemove" the argument passed into the function by the web browser contains all sorts of useful [information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousemove)

According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) Mozilla developer reference, in newer versions of firefox and chrome the console.log function only stores a reference to the object passed into the web browser "which is not necessarily the 'value' of the object at the moment in time you call console.log(), but it is the value of the object at the moment you click it open."

All of the non global values will be relative to .div

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ty very much <3. I have to explain my code tomorrow in front of a bunch of people, you made it clear :) God bless you

Answer (score 0):

From the MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

```
target.addEventListener(type, listener[, options]);
```

listener is 'an object implementing the EventListener interface, or a **JavaScript function**.' (emphasis mine)

You're just passing in a named function (in this case named 'yo').  It would work just as well as an anonymous function.  That is:

```
div.addEventListener('mousemove', function(x) {
  console.log(x);
});
```